# Sort dictionary by value - descending THEN alphabetical C#

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have dictionary: `Dict('a' => 2, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 2)`

I used:

```
var items = from pair in Dict orderby pair.Value descending select pair;
```

Everything is fine and output is:

```
d: 4
b: 3
c: 2
e: 2
a: 2
```

Now I want to sort keys with same value in alphabetical order to get:

```
d: 4
b: 3
a: 2
c: 2
e: 2
```

But I don't have idea how to make it.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Ulug you should make that an answer

Comment: What research have you done on how to use LINQ to order collections of data, and what aspects of what you found in your research were confusing to you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ordering by 2 values, the syntax would be:

```
var items = from pair in Dict 
            orderby pair.Value descending, 
                    pair.Key 
            select pair;
```

Comment: +1, this looks perfect, not really sure why it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your problem correctly then it is as simple as:

```
var items = Dict.OrderByDescending(r=> r.Value)
                .ThenBy(r=> r.Key);
```

You need to order on multiple fields use [`Enumerable.ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) *(or [`Enumerable.ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) depending on your requirement)*

Comment: +1, but it looks like you got hit too for some reason.  Someone's in a bad mood.

Answer (score 4):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
   {"a", 2},
   {"b", 3},
   {"c", 2},
   {"d", 4},
   {"e", 2}
};

var sorted = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenBy(x => x.Key);
```