# Sort Dictionary Array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, sorting

I have Following Array an want to sort it by the time key:

```
Dictionary<string, object>[] callHistory = CharactersPhone.CharactersPhoneCallHistorys_.ToList().Where(x => x.charPhoneNumber == Characters.GetCharacterPhonenumber(charId)).Select(x => 
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"charPhoneNumber" , x.charPhoneNumber.ToString()},
                    {"targetPhoneNumber" , x.targetNumber.ToString()},
                    {"state" , x.state},
                    {"outgoingstate", x.outgoingState},
                    {"time" , x.timestamp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")}
                }).ToArray();
```

I try it with the following:

```
var sorted = callHistory.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(callHistory, x.time))
```

but the key "x.time" is not found, i think i have a little brain lag here or something is fundamental wrong but i doesnt find the answer. Maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044400/sort-dictionary-by-value-descending-then-alphabetical-c-sharp) answer your question?

Comment: The title is confusing. Do you want to sort a dictionary or an array? A dictionary is not an array, and an array is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a `keyed` value as though it were a `property` or `field`.
Instead of accessing it with the `.` operator, use the [`index operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers), as shown below:

```cs
var a = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"charPhoneNumber" , 'a'},
                    {"targetPhoneNumber" , 'b'},
                    {"state" , 'c'},
                    {"outgoingstate", 'd'},
                    {"time" , 'e'}
                };
var b = a["time"];
Console.WriteLine(b); // Outputs "e"
```

In your case, you'd use `x["time"]` in place of `x.time`.

Answer (score 1):

For dictionaries you need to use the indexer:

```
var sorted = callHistory.OrderBy(x => x["time"])
```

I would also note that this sorts it by the *string* values since that's what you use to create the dictionary. I would either keep it as a time and only convert to string when you *display* the data, or store the date/time in a sortable format (e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`)